# How to specify endorsement policy in hyperledge fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i have looked a while for how to set endorsement policy for a chaincode, unfortunately, there is only one similar sample, i.e, http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/endorsement-policies.html

I want to define a simple policy, like "requires TWO signatures from a member of the DEFAULT MSP", how could i set that, thanks.

i think i understand the rule like:

```
peer chaincode deploy -C testchainid -n mycc -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"
```

But how to define if I need more than one signatures in a MSP.

Answer (score 0):

> But how to define if I need more than one signatures in a MSP.

You can leverage `OutOf` notation and write something like

```
OutOf(2, Org1.member)
```

to have endorsement of two peers from Org1 obligatory.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a full sample usage syntax, i did not googled out any guide about the OutOf notation ?

Comment: is there a way for us to specify endorsement from a particular peer. eg:  org1.peer1 and not any other endorsing peer of org1 ?

Comment: No, you cannot specify certain peer of org1.